# How can I merge two complex JSON objects with only unique or different values only showing in resultant array

Tags: javascript, json

If I had two complex JSON objects like:

```
{
 "name": "foo",
 "class": "top",
 "plop": {"class4": "A", "class3": "C", "class2": "B"}
}
```

And

```
{
 "name": "foo",
 "clank": "poop",
 "class": "flop",
 "plop": {"class4": "A", "class3": "A", "class2": "B"}
}
```

How could I merge them such that only unique or different values are in the resultant object? Like so:

```
{
 "clank": "poop",
 "class": "flop",
 "plop": {"class3": "A"}
}
```

Comment: Your arrays are invalid, unless you meant something like `[{"class4": "A", "class3": "A", "class2": "B"}]`

Comment: Zack, I've looked here on stack exchange at $.extend and non-jquery methods of merging Json. Extend seems close to the correct functionality, I would like one value to overwrite the other if it is different. But I want values that are the same to not show in the resultant, merged JSON.

Comment: Patrick, you are exactly right, thank you for your correction. I'd edit my question but it's my understanding that I'd need more positive influence to be able to edit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this, based on Markus' answer to this question:
[How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

```
function MergeRecursiveDiff(obj1, obj2) {

  for (var p in obj2) {
    try {
      // Property in destination object set; update its value.
      if ( obj2[p].constructor==Object ) {
        obj1[p] = MergeRecursiveDiff(obj1[p], obj2[p]);

      } else {
        //Here, I test if the objects are already the same
        if(obj1[p] === obj2[p]) {
            //If they're the same, I delete the first object
            delete(obj1[p]);
        } else {
          obj1[p] = obj2[p];
        }
      }

    } catch(e) {
      // Property in destination object not set; create it and set its value.
      obj1[p] = obj2[p];

    }
  }

  return obj1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your preferred JS programming style, the following might be considered compact and readable:

```
function find_diff(o1, o2) {

    // determine if something is a non-null object
    function is_object(o) { return typeof o === 'object' && o; }

    // handle case where objects are equal or either is undefined
    if (o1===o2 || o1===undefined && o2===undefined) { return undefined; }
    if (o1===undefined) { return o2; }
    if (o2===undefined) { return o1; }

    // implement semantics that second value "wins"
    if (!is_object(o1) || !is_object(o2)) { return o2; }

    // iterate over combined set of keys, constructing a resulting object of diffs
    return Object.keys(o1).concat(Object.keys(o2)).reduce(function(result, key) {
        var val1 = o1[key], val2 = o2[key];

        // find resulting value for this key, based on its presence on one side only,
        // or diff of both values
        var ret = key in o1 ? key in o2 ? find_diff(val1, val2) : val1 : val2;

        // if there is a meaningful (non-undefined) diff, add to result
        if (ret !== undefined) {
            result = result || {};
            result[key] = ret;
        }
        return result;
    }, undefined);

}
```