# Compare two lists in angularJs

Tags: angularjs

I have two list that creat from two different json object:

```
<ul ng-repeat="a in user.data">
    <li>
        <md-checkbox>
              {{ a.name }}
         </md-checkbox>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and :

```
<ul ng-repeat="x in job.data">
    <li>
        <md-checkbox>
              {{ x.user.name }}
         </md-checkbox>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have to compare two lists and remove `{{ a.name }}` that the same as `{{ job.user.name }}` . Comparing json objects that have different structure is hard. How can I compare this two list and remove repeated items?

Comment: By remove you mean filtered? Right? Modifying your original collection will involve code that is not relevant to angular itself but to plain javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `filter` filter ;) using a function instead of a string in the expression argument. Remember this is the syntax of `filter`

```
{{ filter_expression | filter : expression : comparator}}
```

The `expression` can be a string, an object or a function. Something like this will do

```
$scope.filterUnemployed = function(value) {
    var jobs = $scope.job.data;
    for (var i = 0; i < jobs.length; i++) {
        // Search every object in the job.data array for a match. 
        // If found return false to remove this object from the results
        if (jobs[i].user.name === value.name) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    // Otherwise return true to include it
    return true;
}
```

And then apply the filter to your `ng-repeat` directive like this

```
<ul ng-repeat="a in user.data | filter:filterUnemployed">
    <li>
        <md-checkbox>
            {{ a.name }}
        </md-checkbox>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Note that this will not modify your original collection but will result in a new copy beign displayed in your html since this is usually the desired effect.

Check the sample for a working demo

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('SampleCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.user = {
      data: [{
        name: 'John'
      }, {
        name: 'Mary'
      }, {
        name: 'Peter'
      }, {
        name: 'Jack'
      }, {
        name: 'Richard'
      }, {
        name: 'Elizabeth'
      }]
    };
    $scope.job = {
      data: [{
        jobTitle: 'CEO',
        user: {
          name: 'John'
        }
      }, {
        jobTitle: 'CFO',
        user: {
          name: 'Mary'
        }
      }, {
        jobTitle: 'Analist',
        user: {
          name: 'Jack'
        }
      }]
    };
    $scope.filterUnemployed = function(value) {
      var jobs = $scope.job.data;
      for (var i = 0; i < jobs.length; i++) {
        if (jobs[i].user.name === value.name) {
          return false;
        }
      }
      return true;
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="SampleCtrl">
  <h1>All Users</h1>
  <ul ng-repeat="a in user.data">
    <li>
      <md-checkbox>
        {{ a.name }}
      </md-checkbox>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <h1>Unemployed users</h1>
  <ul ng-repeat="a in user.data | filter:filterUnemployed">
    <li>
      <md-checkbox>
        {{ a.name }}
      </md-checkbox>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <h1>Employed</h1>
  <ul ng-repeat="x in job.data">
    <li>
      <md-checkbox>
        {{ x.user.name }}
      </md-checkbox>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new array made from filtering one of your arrays :

```
var newArray = job.data.filter(function(jobData) {
    return user.data.some(function(userData) {
         return userData.name === jobData.user.name;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should help :

```
for(i=0; i<user.data.length;i++){
    for(j=0; j<job.data.length;j++){
        if(user.data[i].name === job.data[j].name){
            user.date.splice(i,1);
        }
    }
}
```

I would appreciate some feedback, at least to know that my code helped you

Answer (score 1):

You can use vanilla javascript, [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) or library [undescore](http://underscorejs.org/).

Please check related links:

[How can I merge two complex JSON objects with only unique or different values only showing in resultant array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25632977/how-can-i-merge-two-complex-json-objects-with-only-unique-or-different-values-on)

[How to merge two object values by keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18498801/how-to-merge-two-object-values-by-keys)

[How to merge two arrays of JSON objects - removing duplicates and preserving order in Javascript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134649/how-to-merge-two-arrays-of-json-objects-removing-duplicates-and-preserving-ord)

[Merging two json objects in Java script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087671/merging-two-json-objects-in-java-script)